# How can I get the user id in js file dynamically if the js file is embedded in another site

Tags: javascript, jquery, embed

I am working on a project where I need to generate the embed code for users so they can integrate a player in their site using the embed code. The code is:

```
<div id="example-player-embed">...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var examp = []; 
examp["_object"] ="example-player-embed"; 
examp["_fid"] = "NDI4NA==";
var _stickyp = _stickyp || []; _stickyp.push(examp);
(function() { 
    var sp = document.createElement("script"); sp.type = "text/javascript";
    sp.async = true; sp.src = "js/example-embed.js";
    var scr = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[document.getElementsByTagName("script").length - 1];
    scr.parentNode.insertBefore(sp, scr); 
})(); 
</script>
```

Now when user embeds the player. It requests a php file `example.php/abcds==` where `abcds==` is the user id which is dynamic. But when I embed the player, the js file is unable to get the id from the embed code. Can anyone please tell me the way how can I do it?

Following is the code in php file. It contains an ajax call to php file to load the content.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:"example.php/abcds==",
    async: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType:'JSON',
    type : 'GET',
    success:function(result){
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
```

Comment: Please beautify your code before posting.

Comment: where do you get the embeded code, show us the code that you get. Your script tag here just creates another script tag, which has path, and would get loaded nomrally. You need to actually create a file on your server so that this script can read it like that.

Comment: Actually I've generated the which I have posted here. The file automatically loads the script on `ready` which embeds the player with the page. Can you please explain how can another file resolve this problem....

Comment: I am still not sure what part of code are you trying to access. you have your file, which is shown up above here, it has a script which does some code and then it appends another script tag with `src=js/example-embeded.js` once you add this script, and this will happen as soon as DOM loads your <script> tag. Your browser will try to interpret it, and this will cause it to attempt to load a script at that address. Whatever is in that script is accessible, but I do not have the content of that script visible here so IDK what is in it, or if it even exists.

Comment: @Dellirium I have updated the question. Please have a look at it...

Comment: "Now when the user embeds the player, it requests a php file" how exactly does this happen, are you sure a request goes to the server, the ajax requested here returns the result, but where is it called from? Your function for result needs to give that result to someone, or store it in some variable for later use. Where is the ajax code that you've shown here written in, how do you use that call, where from?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with data attribute, you can not pass values to js file while loading them into html, only way to pass dynamic value is through a function defined in js file or with data attribute.

```
<div id="example-player-embed" data-var="dynamic-value">...</div>
```